# Callback not working in request npm

Tags: reactjs, npm, callback, request, sails.js

I have some problems with the callback when I'm using Request npm.
My project is an API for the users developed by Sailsjs, on the other hand I'm using reactjs for the front-end, and I'm using Request npm to communicate with the API.
I have some issues with the callback.

My code :

```js
 handleClick(event) {
    var apiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:1337/user";
   if (
      this.state.first_name.length > 0 &&
      this.state.last_name.length > 0 &&
      this.state.email.length > 0 &&
      this.state.password.length > 0
    ) {
      request.post({url : apiBaseUrl + "/store", form :{
        first_name: this.state.first_name,
        last_name: this.state.last_name,
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
      }}, function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          if (response.data.code === 200) {
            var loginscreen = [];
            loginscreen.push(
              <Login
                parentContext={this}
                appContext={this.props.appContext}
                key = {rand}
              />
            );
            var loginmessage = "Not Registered yet.Go to registration";
            this.props.parentContext.setState({
              loginscreen: loginscreen,
              loginmessage: loginmessage,
              buttonLabel: "Register",
              isLogin: true
            });
          } else {
            console.log("some error ocurred", response.data.code);
          }
        });
    } else {
      alert("Input field value is missing");
    }
  }
```

The post request is doing well, when I'm checking the database I found the user saved and the response in networking onglet in chrome is good, but when I do `console.log(response)` it's always `null`. I don't know if my callback isn't right, or if it's something else.

[form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAruM.png)

[image: img1]

[http response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGO4T.png)

[image: img2]

[variables in response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcL2l.png)

[image: img3]

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElH0z.png)

[image: img4]

Back-end

```js
// Store user
  store: function(req, res) {
    var params = _.extend(req.query || {}, req.params || {}, req.body || {});
    console.log(params);
    UserService.store(params, function(err, user) {
      if (err) return res.json();
      if (!user) return res.json();
      return res.send({
        "code": 200,
        "success": "user registered sucessfully"
      });
    });
  },
```

Can you help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Could you show the code on the server side for the POST handler ?

Comment: ok 
that's it : 

// Store user
  store: function(req, res) {
    var params = _.extend(req.query || {}, req.params || {}, req.body || {});
    console.log(params);
    UserService.store(params, function(err, user) {
      if (err) return res.json();
      if (!user) return res.json();
      return res.send({
        "code": 200,
        "success": "user registered sucessfully"
      });
    });
  },

Comment: Please add the code to your question, edit the post and include it for readability.

Comment: ok **done** ...

Comment: replace the first `res.json()` with `res.serverError()` and the second one with `res.notFound()`, I think `res.send({...});` never get executed, you will get this time either an `500` or  `404` error, please try it and see.

Comment: same error mmmm

Comment: you get the response `null` again with a `200 ok` ?

Comment: yeah, the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem is on your callback, the callback takes **two arguments** , it should be like this :

```
function(error, response) {.....}
```

the **error** is the first argument and the response is the second, you are getting `null` because there is **no** error ! and the response was treated as the error object.